# Format codes horizontal whitespace?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts, whitespace, code-formatting

Is there anyway in Visual Studio - in my case I'm using 2012 - to automatically format the amount of white space between code lines?

I know that pressing:

```
ctrl + k + f
```

Will nicely indent my code correctly, so is there an equivalent shortcut for white space gaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant to have a feature from Word, 1.5 line space or double line space then Visual Studio does not have anything like it. The only way to achieve this is to change the font in editor to some that has abnormally large height.